# How to write a function using recursion that takes 2 integers and returns an array containing integers between the 2 input integers

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that will take 2 integers as variables `startNum` and `endNum` and return an array containing all the integers in between the 2 variables.

So for example if we input `(3,6)` we should get as a return an array `[3,4,5,6]`. For this problem we assume that `startNum` will always be smaller than `EndNum`. Also if `startNum` and `endNum` are the same, the function should still work.

I've written the following code but i get an error in the console.

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  
  return startNum === 0 && endNum === 0 ?[]: [startNum,rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1),...endNum];
  
}
```

I get this error message: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Can anyone tell me why it's not working?

Comment: When do you expect `startNum` to become 0?

Comment: why do you use `...endNum`

Comment: That error means you have infinite recursion, which probably means you don't have some base case to stop your recursion once you meet a certain condition.

Comment: You are not stopping when startNum >= endNum

Comment: It would be easier to "reduce" the recursion from one side only, that is, `if a > b` return an empty array, otherwise return `a + range(a + 1, b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple enough change should make the recursive approach work, we keep on calling recursively until the startNum is greater than the endNum.

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
    return startNum > endNum ? [] : [startNum, ...rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum)];
} 

console.log(JSON.stringify(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(rangeOfNumbers(2, 2)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Also, here's a simple way to generate a number range using `Array.from()`.

We generate the resulting array, first by specifying the length, then using the key passed to the populating callback to create the actual contents.

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
    return Array.from( { length: (endNum - startNum + 1) }, (v,k) => startNum + k); 
} 

console.log(JSON.stringify(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The same approach I was about to post, nice one. I suggest adding some explanation, since the OP is clearly a learner.

Comment: @terrylennox this was a training exercise and i have to use recursion.  I understand your base case, but I dont get why i cant use [startNum, rangeOfNumbers(startNum +1), endNum]. I came up with this using the simple example of if we have rangeOfNumbers(1,3) = [1,2, 3] which seems to be [startNum, (startNum+1), endNum]

Comment: @kandé - Because `rangeOfNumbers` returns an array, not just one number. So you spread out that array from the recursive call when building the array for "this" call. You *could* write it so that one of the return paths did `[startNum, ...rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum - 1), endNum]` and that would reduce the number of times it has to recurse, but at the cost of making the function more complex (because you have to handle the case where `startNum === endNum` specially to avoid having duplicates in the result).

Answer (score 1):

```
 function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum)
    { 
      //Add this condition for avoid stack issue
      if(startNum >=endNum) 
          return [];
      if (endNum - startNum === 2)
         return [startNum + 1];
      
      let list = rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1);
      list.push(endNum - 1);
      return list;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Small change in your function to check if `startNum` is greater than `endNum`, return empty array and increment `startNum` at every recursion call.

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (startNum > endNum) {
    return [];
  }
  return [startNum, ...rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum)];  
}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(3, 6));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
    if (startNum == endNum) {
        return [startNum] // Base case
    }
    return [startNum, ...rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum)]
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(rangeOfNumbers(3, 6)));
```

A helpful tip is to figure out what the base case and the subtask are.

In this case, the base case is the situation where `startNum` == `endNum`. A one-element list should be returned.

As for the subtask, you may decompose the task like this:

```js
rangeOfNumbers(3, 6)
= [3, ...rangeOfNumbers(4, 6)]
= [3, ...[4, ...rangeOfNumbers(5, 6)]]
//... and so on
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need recursion to achieve that. You can do it like this:

```
function rangeOfNumbers(start, end) {
    var result = [];
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        result.push(i);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(4,8)); // Outputs: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: I'm new to coding. This is part of  my training. I have to use recursion to solve it.

Comment: It's a good thing to learn recursion, but for the most part you should avoid using it since it could lead to infinite loops/crashes. There's usually a way around using recursion.